# CasperJS inject javascript via this.evaluate

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

Today I tried to inject some javascript logic into remote page using CasperJS with PhantomJS together.

Well, I'm quite surprised because of that:

```
casper.then(function() {
    console.log(this.evaluate(function() {
        function myMethod() {
            return 'Any thing?!';
        }
        return myMethod();
    }));
    console.log(this.evaluate(function() {
        return myMethod();
    }));
});
```

I tried many combinations... Like:

```
casper.evaluate(...)
this.evaluate(...)
casper.page.evaluate(...) <- directly to phantomJS
this.page.evaluate(...)   <- as above
```

First case gives me exactly what I want. But next call to evaluate act as an idiot, which never saw executed code above.

I just want to change variables, functions, and other over remote site js runtime.

Can anybody tell me why this is happening?
Greetings.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense to me, `myMethod` is private to an anonymous function (in the first call). How do you expect it to be available in a different anonymous function *(second call)? You should show what you are actually trying to do so we can suggest something else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot do what you are thinking. `myMethod` is private to the function that is passed to `this.evaluate`. It doesn't make sense that you would expect a private function to be available in another function, just because it was passed to the same method.

In your example, you could try

```
casper.then(function() {
    function myMethod() {
        return 'Any thing?!';
    }
    console.log(this.evaluate(function() {
        return myMethod();
    }));
    console.log(this.evaluate(function() {
        return myMethod();
    }));
});
```

But that is probably not what you are looking for? Or is it?

Or are you trying to attach code to the page itself? Maybe the following?

```
casper.then(function() {
    console.log(this.evaluate(function() {
        // Just creating a variable won't attach it to the window, it will
        // be local to the function. However, you can attach it to the window
        // object, which is in the scope chain
        window.myMethod = function () {return 'anything'};
    }));
    console.log(this.evaluate(function() {
        return myMethod(); // or window.myMethod();
    }));
});
```

Comment: This is what I've been looking for.

Comment: This is what I've been looking for, your second example. Well, I'm not surprised it's private, but I wasn't sure about that, how phantom will inject it into webkit. Firstly I thought, it will pass anonymous function body into page context and this way, it will attach code to window. Thank's for your answer! :)

Comment: is this  fine I inject whole libraries in such way?

Comment: @Копать_Шо_я_нашел I am not sure... There are restrictions on the data that can be shared between the evaluation contexts (can only pass primitives), but you should try it out and post a question if something doesn't work