# CaspserJS assertEval with variables

Tags: casperjs

I'd like to use CasperJS to evaluate a variable equals a certain value.

I simplified my exemple as much as I could that way:

```
var testDate = "24/03/14";
casper.test.begin('TEST', 1, function suite(test) {
    casper.start('http://www.google.com/', function() {
        this.test.assertEval(function() {
            return testDate == "24/03/14";
        }, "testDate is 24/03/14" );
    });
    casper.run(function() {
        this.test.done();
    });
});
```

I don't know why it fails, here is what I get in my console:

```
Test file: tests.js
#TEST
FAIL testDate is 24/03/14
#      type: assertEval
#      file: tests.js:7
#      code: }, "testDate is 24/03/14" );
#      subject: null
#      fn: undefined
#      params: undefined
FAIL 1 test executed in 2.896s, 0 passed, 1 failed, 0 dubious, 0 skipped.

Details for the 1 failed test:

In tests.js:7
   TEST
     assertEval: testDate is 24/03/14
```

Any idea ?

**UPDATE**

I realised my simplified example was faulty, it didn't represent what I really needed.

Actually, what I want to achieve is to test if a variable from the **current page DOM context** equals a **local variable**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok found the answer myself.

To test if a variable from the **current page DOM context** equals a **local variable**, I realised I could use a simple `assertEvalEquals()`:

```
test.assertEvalEquals(function() {
    return variableFromPageDomContext;
}, localVariable);
```

Likewise, when testing if a variable from the **current page DOM context** matches a **RegExp pattern**, we have to use `evaluate()` to get the variable from the DOM as the first parameter of an `assertMatch()`:

```
test.assertMatch(this.evaluate(function() { 
    return variableFromPageDomContext; 
}), RegExpPattern);
```

Hope that can help.

Answer (score 3):

As per [manual](http://casperjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/tester.html) Asserteval:

> Asserts that a code evaluation in remote DOM strictly resolves to a boolean true:

your testdate variable is local to the casperjs script and is not accessible in the remote dom. You would have to inject it to the window like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21559051/2115135).

Comment: Thanks for your help, that's not exactly what I needed but it was my fault as my question was not well formulated. Your answer was interesting and put me on the right track anyway. Updated my question with a solution.

Comment: However, having the same issue with testing if a value from the current page DOM context matches a RegExp pattern... Tried to use `assertMatch()` and `assertEvalEquals()` but didn't work... It can't retrieve the value of variableFromPageDomContext: `test.assertMatch(function() { return variableFromPageDomContext; }, RegExpPattern);` fails and `test.assertEvalEquals(function() { return RegExpPattern.test(variableFromPageDomContext); }, true);` also fails...

Comment: Ok same idea, I should have used **this.evaluate()** to get the value of variableFromPageDomContext: `test.assertMatch(this.evaluate(function() { return variableFromPageDomContext; }), RegExpPattern);`

Answer (score 1):

As @Surreal answers its possible to use the [`assertEvalEquals()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/tester.html#assertevalequals) passing the function and the expected value.

However the original question wants to pass a variable from casperjs context to [`assertEval()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/tester.html#asserteval) function, you can simply do it as follows, passing to `assertEval()` three arguments: the function which receive the value, a message for the assert and the value:

```
var varPassToEval = 'someValue';   
test.assertEval(
        function(varFromCasperContext){
            return varFromPageDomContext === varFromCasperContext;
        },
        'Assert Eval to test', 
        varPassToEval
);
```

With the above example probably is clear to use `assertEvalEquals()` however could be useful for more complex cases, for example imagine that you want to check if a text appears in a some `<li>` inside `<ul>` in DOM which it's dynamic and can change but you don't know at first where your text is... for this case you can use:

```
var somePartOfText = 'blue';   
test.assertEval(
        function(varFromCasperContext){
            return document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].textContent.indexOf(varFromCasperContext) != -1;
        },
        'Assert Eval to test', 
        somePartOfText
);
```

Hope it helps,